# How to fix Syntax Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found end of script in applescript?

Tags: macos, syntax, applescript

I am creating a Mod installer for Minecraft that is for Mac only. It used multiple apps to do one task each (Each was an applescript app). But today I started making one app that does everything. When I completed the script and tried to compile it gives me Syntax Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found end of script.
I think I have everything right but I don't know whats causing this.
Here is the code:

```
say "You are running iCraft version one point one for minecraft version 1.2.5"
display dialog "Which tool do you want to use?" buttons {"Mod Installer", "Backup", "Restore"} default button 3
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result 
    if the button_pressed is "Mod Installer" then
        do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/installer.sh"
            display dialog "Insert all mod files into the Mods folder."
            display dialog "Have you inserted all Mod files into the Mods folder?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
                    if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
                        do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/installer2.sh"
                                display dialog "Finished"
                        else
                            display dialog "Insert mod files into the Mods folder and restart iCraft.app."
                        end if
if the button_pressed is "Backup" then
    display dialog "Are you sure you want to backup your Minecraft.jar in it's current state?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2                       
            if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
                    do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/backup.sh"
                            display dialog "Finished, find it in your Backups directory in the iCraft folder"
            else
                display dialog "Backup aborted"             
            end if
else
    display dialog "Are you sure you want to restore your Minecraft.jar with your backup?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
            if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
                do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/restore.sh"
                        display dialog "Restore finished"
            else
                display dialog "Restore aborted"            
end if
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The last `end if` is actually ending the `if` that's indented, leaving the outer `if` without an `end if`.  Or vice-versa, however you want to look at it.

In other words, add another `end if` before the last line.

Comment: You sir, are epic. Thank you!

Comment: @user1447526: To best thank someone on this site whose answer solves your problem, you can accept their answer by clicking on the green checkmark next to their answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
say "You are running iCraft version one point one for minecraft version 1.2.5"
display dialog "Which tool do you want to use?" buttons {"Mod Installer", "Backup", "Restore"} default button 3
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Mod Installer" then
    do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/installer.sh"
    display dialog "Insert all mod files into the Mods folder."
    display dialog "Have you inserted all Mod files into the Mods folder?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
    if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
        do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/installer2.sh"
        display dialog "Finished"
    else
        display dialog "Insert mod files into the Mods folder and restart iCraft.app."
    end if
    if the button_pressed is "Backup" then
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to backup your Minecraft.jar in it's current state?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
        if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
            do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/backup.sh"
            display dialog "Finished, find it in your Backups directory in the iCraft folder"
        else
            display dialog "Backup aborted"
        end if
    else
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to restore your Minecraft.jar with your backup?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
        if the button_pressed is "Yes" then
            do shell script "~/desktop/iCraft/iCraft.app/contents/resources/scripts/restore.sh"
            display dialog "Restore finished"
        else
            display dialog "Restore aborted"
        end if
    end if
end if
```